# Are these solutions correct using `AsymptoticDSolveValue`? Less::nord: Invalid comparison with I attempted

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, asymptotics

Should one worry about correctness of these solutions due to the messages they generate? Or can one safely ignore these messages?

### Example 1

```
ClearAll[y, t]
ode1 = t^2*y''[t] + t*y'[t] + (1 + t)*y[t] == 0;
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode1, y[t], {t, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

### Example 2

```
ode2 = Sin[t]*y''[t] + Cos[t]*y'[t] + 1/t*y[t] == 0;
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode2, y[t], {t, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

### Example 3

```
ClearAll[y, x]
ode3 = x^2*y''[x] + x/(1 - x^2)^2*y'[x] + y[x] == 0;
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode3, y[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

Version 12.3.1 on windows 10

Comment: For example 1  Maple 2021 produces  `y(t) = _C1*t^(-I)*(1 + (-1/5 - 2*I/5)*t + (-1/40 + 3*I/40)*t^2 + (3/520 - 7*I/1560)*t^3 + (-1/2496 + I/12480)*t^4 + (9/603200 + I/361920)*t^5 + O(t^6)) + _C2*t^I*(1 + (-1/5 + 2*I/5)*t + (-1/40 - 3*I/40)*t^2 + (3/520 + 7*I/1560)*t^3 + (-1/2496 - I/12480)*t^4 + (9/603200 - I/361920)*t^5 + O(t^6))`.